# Finding eigenvalues of a determinant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question regarding finding the eigenvalues of this determinant.

> $$\small
> \left| \begin{matrix}\dfrac{3}{4} - \lambda & \dfrac{1}{3}\\
> \dfrac{1}{4} & \dfrac{2}{3} - \lambda \end{matrix}\right|
> = \left(\dfrac{3}{4} - \lambda\right) \left(\dfrac{2}{3} - \lambda\right) - \dfrac{1}{12} = \lambda^2\ \boxed{-\dfrac{17}{12}\lambda + \dfrac{5}{12}} = (\lambda - 1)\left(\lambda - \dfrac{5}{12}\right) = 0.
> $$

I don't quite understand where these two boxed values are coming from. It's probably something really simple but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I've looked at the equation multiple times and something just isn't clicking. Needless to say I am very stuck and frustrated! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A small correction: you're finding eigenvalues of the matrix, not the determinant.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\dfrac{3}{4} + \dfrac{2}{3} = \dfrac{3\times 3 + 2 \times 4}{3 \times 4} = \dfrac{9 + 8}{12} = \boxed{\dfrac{17}{12}}\\
\dfrac{3}{4}\times\dfrac{2}{3} - \dfrac{1}{12} = \dfrac{6}{12} - \dfrac{1}{12} = \boxed{\dfrac{5}{12}}$$
$\begin{align}
\left( \dfrac{3}{4} - \lambda \right) \left( \dfrac{2}{3} - \lambda \right) - \dfrac{1}{12} &= \dfrac{3}{4} \times \dfrac{2}{3} - \lambda \left( \dfrac{3}{4} + \dfrac{2}{3}\right) + \lambda^2 - \dfrac{1}{12}\\
& = \dfrac{5}{12} - \dfrac{17}{12}\lambda + \lambda^2
\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, where is the 1/12 coming from?

Comment: @user136954 $\left|\begin{matrix}a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right| = ad - bc$. So the $\dfrac{1}{12}$ is the product of the elements $\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: In step 2, wouldn't 12-12=0? Thus, 5/0?

Comment: No, that's not how you subtract fractions. You can subtract a fraction from another if both have the same denominator, by subtracting their numerators and keeping the denominator the same. If the denominator is not the same, use the LCM to make them equal.
See http://www.mathsisfun.com/fractions_subtraction.html or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvD_I8tnOV4